# Paypal Express Checkout with Smart Button Console Error

Tags: button, paypal, express-checkout

Integrated Paypal Express checkout with Smart Button SDK. While clicking on that button, open a pop up window.

Before rendering page in pop up window, I click popup browser close button, which generates console error "window_closed".

How I can handle this event in error handling mechanism? I already added onCancel clause while rendering paypal smart button.

Can anyone help me on this!